# How to display the word "AMS-LaTeX" in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

How do I display the word "AMS-LaTeX" properly in LaTeX like in the image below?[image]

Is there a command for the "AMS" part similar to `\LaTeX`?

Comment: just a random comment from the "home front":  the ams staff finds the first part of that logo a bit too fussy, and are not using it for documents emerging from this office.  just "AMS" (all caps) will do fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Short version:
\AmS-\LaTeX\par
Manual version:
\makeatletter
{\AmSfont A\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {M}\kern -.125emS}-L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15emT\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}
 \AmS-\LaTeX
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or the Heiko Oberdiek version... contains a lot of logos you might need.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hologo}

\begin{document}
\hologo{AmSLaTeX}
\end{document}
```

Or you just type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
$\cal A$\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{$\cal M$}\kern-.125em$\cal S$-\TeX
\end{document}
```